# How to Count Combinations In a Set (Including dupes)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Trying to figure out a formula where I have 5 columns of text data. I want to count how many times combinations of data in 2 contiguous columns appear in each row.

Example data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | A | A | A | B | C |
| **2** | A | B | B | A | A |

In the example data above there are 8 range pairs (4 ranges per row):

|  | Paired Cells 1 | Paired Cells 2 | Paired Cells 3 | Paired Cells 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Row 1** | `{A1:B1}` | `{B1:C1}` | `{C1:D1}` | `{D1:E1}` |
| **Row 2** | `{A2:B2}` | `{B2:C2}` | `{C2:D2}` | `{D2:E2}` |

From the paired ranges there are eight unique value pairs:

| Unique Paired Values | Count | Paired Cell Locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **`{A,A}`** | 3 | `A1:B1` `B1:C1` `D2:E2` |
| **`{A,B}`** | 2 | `C1:D1` `A2:B2` |
| **`{B,C}`** | 1 | `D1:C1` |
| **`{B,B}`** | 1 | `B2:C2` |
| **`{B,A}`** | 1 | `C2:D2` |
|  |  |  |
| &nbsp | **Count Total: 8** | **Paired Cells Total: 8** |

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

#### Formula 1: Separate Counts For Each Row

This formula provides a separate count for each row's combinations.

```
={ "ROW #", "COMBO", "COUNT";
    ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(
      BYROW(
        QUERY( 
          TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",
            BYROW(A:E, LAMBDA(rB, IF(INDEX(rB,,1)="", IFERROR(1/0), JOIN(";",
              MAP(SEQUENCE((COUNTA(rB)-1)), LAMBDA(r, 
                ROW(rB) & "," & INDEX(rB,,r) & INDEX(rB,,r+1)))))))),";")),
          "Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) group by Col1 label COUNT(Col1) '' "),
        LAMBDA(rC, JOIN(",",rC))),",")) }
```

**<sup>Formula 1: Separate Counts For Each Row</sup>**
[image]

#### Formula 2: Combined Counts Across All Rows

This formula gives a combined count for combinations across all rows.

```
={ "COMBO", "COUNT";
   QUERY(
     TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";", TRUE, 
       BYROW(A:E, LAMBDA(rB, IF(INDEX(rB,,1)<>"",
         JOIN(";", MAP(SEQUENCE((COUNTA(rB)-1)), LAMBDA(r, 
           INDEX(rB,,r) & INDEX(rB,,r+1)))),
         IFERROR(1/0) )))),
       ";")),
     "select Col1, COUNT(Col1) group by Col1 label COUNT(Col1) ''"
   )
 }
```

**<sup>Formula 2: Combined Counts Across All Rows</sup>**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `let()`, `offset()`, `map()`, `flatten()` and `query()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  next_, lambda(cell, offset(cell, 0, 1)), 
  pair_, lambda(cell, join("-", cell, next_(cell))), 
  query( 
    flatten(map(A1:D2, pair_)), 
    "select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

See [let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535), [offset()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093379), [map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985), [flatten()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) and [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343).